# Access file from JS running localy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, google-chrome

I need to load a simple .CSV file from JS (That's not the problem here), but the "script" need to be portable (i will use it as the screen on a competition), and score data will be inserted in the CSV, and JS will be updating it's data based on the CSV.

But my problem here is: I need to run it without apache or a server, because i cant make shure the people who will use it, will have apache and also Internet... It need to be opened from a folder (Just a HTML with JS, and a file in the same folder with the .CSV)

When i try to access files from jQuery (`$.get(..., ..., "jsonp")`, and `$.get()`), Chrome output this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:PATHTOTHEFILE Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

This happens because the browser blocks it's content (for security reasons).

How can i "deal" with this problem, or do you know a better solution, to save some simple data and read it from JS without secury problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add  --allow-file-access-from-files to the chrome startup command line

make a BAT file and get you users to click that to start your app

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe ^
--allow-file-access-from-files ^
http://bing.co.uk
```

swap out the http:// for you file url.

Comment: Is there another way of doing this, that any "dumb" person can use?

Comment: @Ivan Looks like no: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121406 -- this bug is merged with a larger bug that is still unresolved. However, you could make create a shortcut to Chrome and add the flag to the path in Properties (slightly easier than making a batch script IMHO).

Comment: It solved, but it's not "perfect"... it's a kind of "work-around" ^^ But thanks any way! =]

Comment: The BAT script is 'portable', the Shortcut will require path surgery...easier for who?

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 FileReader. But in this way you have to select file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<label for="files">Path to file: </label><input type="file" id="files" name="files[]"/>
<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var f;
        for (var i = 0; f = files[i]; i++) {
            if (!f.type.match('text.*')) {
                continue;
            }
            var reader = new FileReader('test.html');
            reader.onloadend = (function () {
                return function(e) {
                  alert(e.target.result);
                };
            })();
            reader.readAsText(f);
        }
    }



    var fileSerf= document.getElementById('files');
    if (fileSerf){
        fileSerf.addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

example: http://jsbin.com/ozeyag/293/